# Getting Blank record for this code

Tags: php

Look at this code, i am getting empty record in database.

`$firstname=isset($_POST['firstname'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']):"";`

this line not giving first name but it gives blank value not the value that i am trying to insert into the database.

whats wrong in this code?

**create.php**

```
<?php
    include_once('confi.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        $firstname=isset($_POST['firstname'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']):"";
        $lastname=isset($_POST['lastname'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']):"";
        $email=isset($_POST['email'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']):"";
        $password=isset($_POST['password'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']):"";
        $status=0;

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email,password,status) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password','$status')";
        $insert = mysql_query($query);
        if($insert)
        {
            $data=array("result"=>1,"message"=>"successfully added!");
        }
        else
        {
            $data=array("result"=>0,"message"=>"Error!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data=array("result"=>0,"message"=>"Request Method is Wrong!");
    }


    mysql_close($conn);
    /* JSON Response */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**confi.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('tuts_rest', $conn);
?>
```

Comment: can you add the HTML code here, i dough that you may be using GET method in <form> tag.

Comment: @AmitShah if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'` is true it's obvioulsy `method="POST"`

Comment: Check field names of your form. Maybe it's `first_name` or just `name`. Or just `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: that is fine, but lets say if form method is get you will not get post data. as a result you need to print post data and see if you are getting in post or via some other method.

Comment: that is via i told you give me your HTML form to debug it further.

Comment: thanx to all but i am using Advance REST client crome extention for passing the data to Database

Comment: Please show us the output of: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: it gives error "Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call"

Comment: There is no isset anywhere in: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: i cant print because values are comming in json form so it displays only Unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines  in your php file and remove header access you have already added

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') 
    {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:            
    {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: i am sending data using advance REST client crome extention

Comment: Okay try next answer I have added. Pls replace your php file headers